# How to override builtin Completion file?

Tags: zsh

I have made some modifications in `_stow` completion file.

I want to override `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Completion/Unix/_stow` with `$HOME/.dotfiles/.resources/zsh-dotfiles/zsh-custom-completions/_stow`

I have put the following on my `.zshrc`

```
fpath=($HOME/.dotfiles/.resources/zsh-dotfiles/zsh-custom-completions $fpath)
```

`print -rl -- $fpath` output show that the path is added.

Still it is calling the builtin completion file instead of the new completion file.

What can I do?

Comment: This should be enough. If you called your own completion for `stow` something different, you could run into the cache, which is automatically updated when a new completion function is added but not when one is modified. However that cache only contains the association `stow` → `_stow`, not the code of the completion function itself. What does `echo $functions[_stow]` show when zsh has just started, before doing any completion of `stow`? Post a log of doing the first completion for `stow` which `^X?` (`complete-debug`).

Comment: `echo $functions[_stow]` shows `builtin autoload -XU`. I got the `complete-debug`. It is a large file.  Here is the link https://zerobin.net/?a6a06a645c5a5e10#98LK321tjSNfHoxqof9pkX30sffL8UsyvVT1yJBuytU=

Comment: That's a completion of command names, not a completion of `stow` arguments. You need to type at least `stow` and a space, then press `^X?`.

Comment: Sorry, This is the new link. https://zerobin.net/?da09c9e272045822#9ApPuA1cS5dMIfltUzQshWR6upoJSXV/DG3S0eSCdLk=